# javascript variable not setting (possible jquery issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've got the a piece of a form where I've applied some javascript (the end-purpose of the js is to show the appropriate follow up question), but the part that loads the `input`'s and `select`'s values into variables doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the exact code:

```
# HTML
<ul id="m_mlt_t">
<li>How long have you known <span class="nom">__</span>?</li>
    <li><input name="m_mlt_n" type="text" maxlength="3" /> <select name="m_mlt_t"><option></option><option>days</option><option>months</option><option>years</option></select></li>
    <li><input name="m_mlt_n" type="radio" value="777" />I prefer not to answer</li>
    <li><input name="m_mlt_n" type="radio" value="999" />Don't know</li>
    <li><span class="m_mlt_t" style="display:none;"></span></li>
</ul>

# JAVASCRIPT
$('select[name="m_mlt_t"], input[name="m_mlt_n"]').change(function() {
    var time = $('input[name="m_mlt_n"]').val();
        $("span#m_mlt_t").text(time);
        $("span#m_mlt_t").fadeIn();
    var period = $('select[name="m_mlt_t"]').val();
        $("span#m_mlt_t").append(" " + period);
        $("span#m_mlt_t").fadeIn();
});
```

In the fiddle, I expect the span to fade in and display the values of the textfield and the dropdown.
http://jsfiddle.net/vxvSU/

---

btw the code for the following custom functions isn't included, but I know they work
`counter_multiChoice()`,`fadeOUT_sect()`,`fadeIN_sect()`

Comment: your code is short enough to post here too - please do so!

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`.

Comment: I'm sure **you** know those other functions work, but the javascript engine doesn't, and won't let us see what's going wrong without them including the `undefined` qArray...

Comment: okay, i'll remove it from the code.

Comment: All I did was remove your line of code and add the comma like I originally suggested ... http://jsfiddle.net/vxvSU/4/

Comment: Hmm, when I put in the rest of the working js, it stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/As5kV/

Comment: Ohh, ugh I'm an idiot: I changed `<span id="` to `<span class="`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first problem is your selector

```
$('select[name="m_mlt_t"] input[name="m_mlt_n"]')
```

This selects any **child** input elements inside the select element, which doesn't make any sense and should probably be...

```
$('select[name="m_mlt_t"], input[name="m_mlt_n"]')
```

Which selects all matching select, **and** input elements with the appropriate names.

Comment: Thank you! (filler text to meet min req)